# Product details in admin panel not displaying in magento

Tags: magento, product

The product details in admin panel not displaying, It showing me a blank page. And also product image in front end also not displaying(media.phtml is not at all calling). It is due to magento extension, I installed and uninstalled still showing error. Please someone help me..

Thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried clearing the cache of magento. Clear this using cache management from system menu in admin panel. I once faced the same issue when I used an extension for creating product brochure. When I removed this extension manually by deleting all the files and not using magento connect for uninstalling the modules, same problem as yours happened. Be sure all files for the module mainly blocks and any admin html blocks or layout still exist from that module. And clear the magento cache.

Comment: I removed xml file of extension and also removed cache still products not displaying in admin panel

Comment: Which extension you installed in the magento and is this module dependent of the catalog of magento.

Comment: I installed Apptha price countdown timer extension, When i faced this problem immediately i uninstalled it but the products not showing in admin panel.

Comment: I tried to work on this extension and it seems this is not available now. Are you sure you haven't removed any core files. There is no chance this could happen if only you uninstall an extension.

Comment: No .. I didn't even touch the core files.. I am modifying everything in my theme only.... BTW Can u tell me which core file displays the product details in admin panel?

Comment: /pathtoproject/projectname/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml and all the files inside the /pathtoproject/projectname/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/ directory is responsible for showing products in the admin panel. Also look into /pathtoproject/projectname/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php and /pathtoproject/projectname/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/ directory for any changes.

Comment: thank u very much Akash for your response, i run my backup and solved the issue.. i think the problem in database table..

Comment: GLAD UR PROBLEM IS SOLVED.